# How to reload a entire component with angular when route changes?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I want to reload or rerender a sidebar component when route change i have the following code:

```
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    this.auth.currentUser.subscribe(x => this.userData = x);
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        console.log('enter');
      }
    });
  }
```

This enter to show the log 'enter' but not reload the component. Anybody can help with an example?

Comment: Can you describe why you would like to reload sidebar component?

Comment: Because ithe styles from template are in jquery an this not load after reloading the page

Answer (score 1):

Usually component routing doesn't reload because angular works as SPA(single page application) - but you can make your `components` to load in order to reduce the browser size if that is the only case

Use `href` and your path name insted of `routerLink` on your sidebar `anchor` link - this will make your component to reload everytime when you click - everytime it will load all your `js` from server - if you are using `lazy` load this process is not the right way - this will only helps you to reduce the browser RAM usage on every click and doesn't maintain any previous data but routing will work as the same

So `href` will be the word for your question - but make sure that you really want to load your components

Hope it helps - Happy Coding:)

Comment: I want to re-render the component because the styles are in jquery and this works fine but when i change the route this component loses the styles an dproperties afeter reloading the page again...

Comment: Yeah !! It reload the entire page completely - I'm not sure about your styles please add some code to check :)

Comment: This jquery not aplly styles until refresh the page [Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rypiwy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.js) and loses the style when change route until refresing again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the entire page, just use

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: I need to reload only a component, not the whole page